# SQLite insert if not existing, otherwise perform simple addition on current value

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to develop a query to a SQLite database that will allow me to INSERT if the name does not exist, if it does exist I need to perform a simple addition using the current value in the table so I can add to it.

I'm using this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  name text unique,
  time integer
);
```

So far I've come across using this which does work in a way. It will not replace existing records that feature the name, it will update them instead as I like.

```
insert or ignore into users (name, time) values ('username', 100);
update users set time = time + abs(time - (time + 100)) where name = 'username';
```

The problem with this query is that if the name does not exist, it will both set the value **and** do the addition.

Is there any way I can prevent the addition from happening if the username does not exist? Or is there another route that I could try?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: insert it with time value 0. Then the update statement will increment it by 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of cha's and LS_dev's methods are correct and work exactly how I want them to. Thanks a bunch.

I can't believe I missed either of those solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Just swapping your statements would work!!!

```
update users set time = time + abs(time - (time + 100)) where name = 'username';
insert or ignore into users (name, time) values ('username', 100);
```

`UPDATE` would only change existing rows, `INSERT` would only create new rows!

Additional note: `abs(time - (time + 100))` = `100`